# How to prevent my Linux notebook fom waking up from sleep when a bluetooth device is connected?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, sleep, wake-up

When I have my bluetooth headphones connected to my computer and send the notebook to sleep, it will wake up again after a few seconds. Combined with the auto-sleep timeout, this cycle will continue until the bluetooth device becomes unavailable or the battery runs flat.

How can I prevent my notebook from waking up constantly as long as a bluetooth device is connected?

Comment: It was `XHCI` for me:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/772229/143394

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a systemd service to run `rfkill` every time your machine goes to sleep:

1. Create a new file under `/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth-prevent-wake.service` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=disable bluetooth for systemd sleep/suspend targets
Before=sleep.target
Before=suspend.target
Before=hybrid-sleep.target
Before=suspend-then-hibernate.target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

ExecStart=/usr/bin/rfkill block bluetooth
ExecStop=/usr/bin/rfkill unblock bluetooth

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
WantedBy=suspend.target
WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
WantedBy=suspend-then-hibernate.target
```

2. run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
3. run `sudo systemctl enable --now bluetooth-prevent-wake.service` to start and enable the new service